# How to change text of a button in my current fragment, when I click a button on my Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity in which I add/remove fragments.
I want to change the text of a button in my current fragment, when I click another button in the activity.
How to achieve this?

I am adding fragment to the activity as follows:

```
private void navigateToPostAd() {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments


    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = new PostAdA();


    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack("post_ad").commit();


    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

In the main activity I am doing the following

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

        location = (String)loadFromSharedPrefs("location");


       PostAdA fragment = new PostAdA();
        if(fragment.getBtnSelectCity() != null) {
            fragment.getBtnSelectCity().setText(location);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not figure out a proper piece of code for this.

Comment: what are you using to change fragments? ViewPager? please post your code so we can help more.

Answer (score 2):

If you're replacing your `FrameLayout` with `Fragment` you could declare the Fragment as a local variable.

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
```

on your `MyFragment` have a getter for the button

```
public Button getButton() {
    return mButton;
}
```

when there's an `onClick` in your Activity's button just call the `fragment.getButton()` and `setText()`

If you're using a `ViewPager`, call your `PagerAdapter`'s `getItem(int position)` and do the same thing. Which will look like this:

```
((MyFragment) mAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem())).getButton().setText("Your Text");
```

Either way You need a getter for your `Button` and a way to access your `Fragment`.

Edit: Your problem here is that you're creating a new instance of `PostAdA` In your initial declaration of the `fragment` object make it a `class variable` i.e.

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {

    Fragment fragment;

    private void navigateToPostAd() {
        // update the main content by replacing fragment
        fragment = new PostAdA();
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack("post_ad").commit();
        } else {
        // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            location = (String)loadFromSharedPrefs("location");
            if(fragment != null) {
                fragment.getBtnSelectCity().setText(location);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this
 PostAdA fragment = new PostAdA();
            if(fragment.getBtnSelectCity() != null) {
                fragment.getBtnSelectCity().setText(location);
            }

But it did not work

Comment: could you update your question with your current implementation @pagalpanda ?

Comment: @pagalpanda check out the answer :)

Comment: don't forget to accept it if that helped you out ;)

Comment: Just an FYI as well that if `fragment` is reading null at any time, even though it should be present, you can reset it with `fragment = (PostAdA) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);`

Comment: private void navigateToPostAd() method is part of another fragment from which I am removing and adding the PostAdA fragment.

onOptionsItemSelected is part of the main activity, of which both the fragments are part of

Comment: @PPartisan If I do this I get an error for inconvertible types:
Cannot cast android.app.Fragment to PostAdA

Comment: @pagalpanda Yea, `Fragment fragment` will need to be replaced with `PostAdA fragment`. If you leave it as `Fragment fragment` you can probably get away without casting it (`(PostAdA)`), but then you wouldn't be able to access any of the methods associated with `PostAdA`

Comment: My fragment is of type
android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

and the getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
is of type android.app.fragment.

@PPartisan

Comment: @pagalpanda Then it's up to you to decide whether you're going to use regular or support fragments. In your question you use `getFragmentManager()`, which will only work with `android.app.Fragment`.